How to make c++ compiler distinguish between std::function<void()> and std::function<asio::awaitable<void>()> parameters?
In my another question, I learned that std::function<asio::awaitable<void>()> can be automatically converted to std::function< void()>. This leads to a problem like the following:
I need to write a function with two overloads that accept two callbacks: std::function<asio::awaitable<void>()> or std::function<void()>. Based on the previous question, it's clear that this won't work.
But if you change it to only accept std::function<void()> type callbacks. While passing in std::function<asio::awaitable<void>()> type callbacks would be equally legal, the true return value of the callback would not be available inside the function.
Of course it could be written as 2 functions with different names. But the problem still remains, the version of std::function<void()> will lead to very easy misuse. Because even if you accidentally pass std::function<asio::awaitable<void>, the compiler will not report an error.
Any ideas on how to solve the above problem?

You are mixing up std::function and the callables you want to store in them. My answer doesn't talk about conversion between std::function<asio::awaitable<void>()> and std::function< void()>, just about conversion from callables in general to these types. Because of that confusion "I need to write a function with two overloads that accept two callbacks: [...]" asks something completely different that you want to ask. Please show an actual [mre].

To be clear, because that tends to confuse beginners: std::function is not the type of a function, lambda or other callable in C++. It is a container to store different callable objects of different types that can be called in the same way without need to template on the specific callable type. When passing callables as arguments to a function, a template is usually a better approach than using std::function. std::function should only be used if there is a specific reason for it, e.g. in interfaces that can't be templated.

Does it help to use a concept of the return type?  E.g. template <T> concept returns_awaitable_void = std::is_same_t<std::invoke_result_t<T>, asio::awaitable<void>>;   You could use it and its negation to constrain the overloads (if if constexpr isn't sufficient, instead of overload).

Use a concept on the return type of the callable you pass.  Such as returns_awaitable_void in this demonstration program:
namespace asio
{
    template<typename T> struct awaitable {};
}

#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept returns_awaitable_void =
    std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<T>, asio::awaitable<void>>;

void f(returns_awaitable_void auto&& g)
{
    std::clog << "in f(returns_awaitable_void&&)\n";
    g();
}

template<std::invocable Callable>
void f(Callable&& g)
    requires (not returns_awaitable_void<Callable>)
{
    std::clog << "in f(Callable&&)\n";
    g();
}

void foo() {}

asio::awaitable<void> bar() { return {}; }


int main()
{
    f(foo);
    f(bar);
}


Using concept does work, but it's hard to transform my code into a template, I'm using the paradigm of hiding the implementation in the cpp file, changing to a template implies moving the implementation to the header file, which is probably not doable!

Not necessarily - you might be able to explicitly instantiate the template in one translation unit.  Or provide the overloads as templates (in the header) that simply forward to two distinct functions (defined in the implementation file) accepting a std::function each.

Don't think of templates as "hard" think of them as a part of C++ you don't know well (yet). They're an integral part of C++, and learning about them will make you a much better C++ programmer. They might have been harder in the past (early 2000's) but since then compiler and debugger support made them much more easy to use (debug/maintain)

you are right, I can move really impl method to private block, and add a proxy template mehtods in public block.

@PepijnKramer My focus has never been on whether the template is hard or not. Rather, it's whether it solves the problem or not. If I have to talk about whether templates are good or not, then I don't think they're good because they make compilation errors hard to understand and are very IDE-unfriendly, seriously degrading the coding experience. But I'll still use it if I need to.

In C++20 you can use concepts (or in C++17 SFINAE) to "disable" implicit type conversions like this :
#include <functional>

namespace asio
{
template<typename type_t>
struct awaitable
{
};
}

template<typename signature_t>
concept VoidFunction = std::is_same_v<std::function<void()>,std::function<signature_t>>;

// use a concept or in C++ SFINAE to disable "implicit" type conversion
// now this function will only accept an explicit match
void func(auto VoidFunction /*cb*/)
{
}

void func(std::function<asio::awaitable<void>()> /*cb*/)
{
}

int main()
{
    func([]() -> asio::awaitable<void> {
       // co_return;
    });
}


Your solution works. But is there a way to disable implicit type conversion without using templates?

Why isn't the concept just VoidFunction = std::same_as<void(),signature_t>;?

@WeijunZhou Explicitness, I really mean std::function so I do not shorten it to something I don't want to express

I'm using the paradigm of hiding the implementation in the cpp file, changing to a template implies moving the implementation to the header file, which is probably not doable!

@vipcxj Make a distinction between publicly visible header files, and the ones you use within your implementation. Templates can be local in a cpp file or in a local header file

Synthesizing the responses from @TobySpeight and @PepijnKramer, here's my final solution
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <functional>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
template<typename T>
concept VoidFunction = std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<T>, void>;

void func(VoidFunction auto cb)
{
    cb();
}
void func(std::function<asio::awaitable<void>()> cb)
{}

int main()
{
    func([]() -> void {
        return;
    });
}

A little problem with @PepijnKramer's answer.
template<typename signature_t>
concept VoidFunction = std::is_same_v<std::function<void()>,std::function<signature_t>>;

will cause
    func([]() -> void {
        return;
    });

compilation failed. The concept doesn't match this lambda very well.
Also my implementation is hidden in the cpp file, and the following changes were made to enable the use of the template
class MyClass
{
private:
  std::shared_ptr<MyClassImpl> m_state;
  void func_1(std::function<void()> cb);
  void func_2(std::function<asio::awaitable<void>()> cb);
public:
  void func(VoidFunction auto cb)
  {
    func_1(std::move(cb));
  }
  void func(std::function<asio::awaitable<void>()> cb)
  {
    func_2(std::move(cb));
  }
};

